# GRPC C++ Build from Source Fatal error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, grpc

Want to try and use GRPC C++ (have experience with Java version), and I am trying to build GRPC C++ from source as instructed in the installation instructions posted on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Following these instructions the build fails at the following:

```
[CXX]     Compiling src/cpp/util/time_cc.cc
[HOSTCXX] Compiling src/compiler/cpp_generator.cc
In file included from ./src/compiler/cpp_generator.h:29:0,
             from src/compiler/cpp_generator.cc:21:
./src/compiler/config.h:25:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h: No such file or directory
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am trying to build this on Ubuntu 17.10

Could some one help?

Comment: I have done this on Debian 9 which is reasonably close to Ubuntu 17.10 so this seems very possible. That being said, the first thing that jumps out at me from your error message is did you grab the git submodules and place them in the correct directory?

Comment: Well, after cloning the git repo i also did:

"git submodule update --init" 
The instructions did not mention anything about moving files/directories?

Comment: The protobuf dependency may have changed and grpc did not update its code accordingly. The build status for grpc is currently 404'd. This is one of the reasons not to use git submodules in the first place, but you are stuck using them here. Can you check the protobuf submodule to see if that header file does indeed exist there?

Comment: Just checked, it does exist in "third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler". I think it might have protoc installed anyways on my machine. I appear to have protoc installed already on my machine. Could it be trying to check against that one?

Comment: If CMake is preferring that install then maybe. I did the build on a Vagrant box so the system environment was clean and minimal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like protobuf broken master. I successfully compiled after switching to v3.4.1 :

```
cd third_party/protobuf/
git checkout v3.4.1
cd -
sudo make HAS_SYSTEM_PROTOBUF=false install
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a protobuf version incompatible with the grpc is installed on the workstation.